# login with Fb and Google using Ionic

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I am trying to integrate fb login and google login with ionic framework .

Any idea which plugin suits best . I had tried **InappBrwoser** Plugin , giving me error "**Could not find InAppBrowser Plugin**". but i am not successful on the same.

Any help on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea whch plugin suits best

Yes, [this plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/).

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.facebookLogin = function() {
    $cordovaOauth.facebook("CLIENT_ID_HERE", ["email"]).then(function(result) {
        // results
    }, function(error) {
        // error
    });
    }

    // $cordovaOauth.dropbox(string appKey);
    // $cordovaOauth.digitalOcean(string clientId, string clientSecret);
    // $cordovaOauth.google(string clientId, array appScope);
    // $cordovaOauth.github(string clientId, string clientSecret, array appScope);
    // $cordovaOauth.linkedin(string clientId, string clientSecret, array appScope, string state);
    // $cordovaOauth.instagram(string clientId, array appScope);
    // $cordovaOauth.box(string clientId, string clientSecret, string state);
    // $cordovaOauth.reddit(string clientId, string clientSecret, array appScope);
    // $cordovaOauth.twitter(string consumerKey, string consumerSecretKey);
    // $cordovaOauth.meetup(string consumerKey);
    // $cordovaOauth.foursquare(string clientId);
    // $cordovaOauth.salesforce(string loginUrl, string clientId);
    // $cordovaOauth.strava(string clientId, string clientSecret, array appScope);
});
```

Comment: it is giving me error . Could not find InAppBrowser Plugin

Comment: Did you add the plugin? `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` and are you testing on a device?

Comment: yes, i did the same,. and i am testing on real device

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use [Hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js/) that is a great JS librairy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-cordova just update the library and remove the plugin inappbrowser from your project and add the plugin this way "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser", the old library try to find "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" but the correct name for this plugin is "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser".

Answer (score 0):

NPM provides the package called `angular4-social-login`

> Social login and authentication module for Angular 4 / 5. Supports
>   authentication with Google and Facebook. Can be extended to other
>   providers also.

[Package for social media login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-social-login)